# How can I learn de casteljau algorithm? (from calculus)

Tags: geometry, bezier-curve

I'm an highschool graduate who is currently waiting for college.

Meanwhile, I'm trying to do a little project by myself. (Computer stuff) And yesterday, I found that I needed to deal with something called "De Casteljau algorithm"

I know calculus (single-variable, but I'm thinking about learning multi-)
and I don't want an empty 'memorize-without-understanding-or-proving' approach.

Which path will take me there?
(I'm hoping for answers like:
"Calculus -> Differential Eq -> ...")

p.s: I would also appreciate book/video lecture recommendations :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you need the De Casteljau algorithm for? You might be able to use other methods and get good results. Anyway, it believe you have the required mathematical tools to work and understand De Casteljau's algorithm.

Here is a similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271817/casteljaus-algorithm-practical-example

search on computer graphics websites and you will get more information with examples. here is one such example
http://www.cc.gatech.edu/classes/AY2007/cs3451_fall/bezier.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try [The Essentials of CAGD](http://www.farinhansford.com/books/essentials-cagd/) by  Farin and Hansford. All books by Farin are very nice.

Comment: I would have to disagree with this statement. I am in Farin/Hansford's CAGD class at ASU and I have the book. It is nothing more than a reference for people who already know what they are looking at. Trust me, it is impossible to learn the concepts from the book. If you read the reviews on Amazon, you will see similar comments. This site: http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/ may be of some use, however.